# Percentage of time of an evaluation used to perform the evaluation

Tags: agile-testing

I often need to evaluate the time required to test a modification and include this time into the evaluation.

What is the average percentage of the time evaluated that should be used to perform the evaluation ?

For example, if I evaluate the testing time of a modification to 9 hours and it takes me 1 hour to do the evaluation my evaluation will be 10 hours. This mean that 10% of the evaluated time has been used for the evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the average percentage of the time evaluated that should be
>   used to perform the evaluation?

I would say that the question itself doesn't make sense, because ["the value of any practice depends on its context"](http://context-driven-testing.com/). It barely matters how much time other people in other projects dedicate for planning because they are acting in a different context.

**Your** planning should take as long it needs to take since [you need this time to technical excellence and good design](https://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html). Naturally, you can [at regular intervals, reflect on how to become more effective, then tune and adjust your behavior accordingly](https://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html).

Other's planning will aim may aim at the same, but since the context is different, the planning itself will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right the best for me actually is to compare with people working in the same domain as me.

Comment: Beware that "domain" is one of the aspects of context. Context includes all sorts of characteristics, from team size, company growth expectations, coding and management practices, etc. Microsoft and tech startups can be of the same "domain", but the context of its products are very different.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking `How to factor the time it takes for test effort estimation` is that correct? Below is how I define `Test Effort Estimation`

> The planning activity where you look at the entire `System Under Test` and try to estimate the effort it is going to take to test the system. Effort obviously includes the time factor and should in some way try to answer `How long will the testing take?`.

The important point I am willing to make here is that these are two different phases, *ie* Test Estimation and Test Execution and I do not see why you want to count both as testing time. It makes sense sometimes to look at the entire software life cycle of a feature to see how much effort all together went into that but then there are a lot more factors that will go into that *ex* test planning, effort estimation, reporting and analysis time etc.

I hope I answered what you were looking for, if not please let me know, and I would love to understand your question better.

Comment: Hello Akash, You are right i updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Hi Mr. Rubix. So now since I am sure what you are looking for I will again highlight **not to mix up the test estimation and test execution estimates** to be just test execution estimates. The difficulty is (possibly you are facing that as well) that both those phases do not happen always around the same time, and the other potential management issue can be that we convey the wrong message and set the wrong cadence if we show the test planning, test estimation and test execution to be estimates for just one activity -- test execution.